# Google Roboto Fonts - cannot install due to conflicts

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, fonts

On a new minimal install of 16.04, Google's Roboto fonts are not showing in Chrome.

When I try to install the fonts I get a `conflicts`... message. Any ideas how to fix?

```
one@laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install fonts-roboto*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fonts-roboto-fontface' for glob 'fonts-roboto*'
Note, selecting 'fonts-roboto-hinted' for glob 'fonts-roboto*'
Note, selecting 'fonts-roboto' for glob 'fonts-roboto*'
Note, selecting 'fonts-roboto-unhinted' for glob 'fonts-roboto*'
fonts-roboto is already the newest version (2:0~20160106-1).
fonts-roboto-hinted is already the newest version (2:0~20160106-1).
fonts-roboto-hinted set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fonts-roboto-hinted : Conflicts: fonts-roboto-unhinted but 2:0~20160106-1 is to be installed
 fonts-roboto-unhinted : Conflicts: fonts-roboto-hinted but 2:0~20160106-1 is to be installed
                         Conflicts: fonts-roboto-hinted:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
one@laptop:~$
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a 16.04 bug which is not present in 17.10. I just filed a [bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1760124) and uploaded a fix, and it should be fine in a couple of weeks or so.

*Edit:*

Fixed now:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-roboto/2:0~20160106-1ubuntu0.1

Comment: thank you! I will marked this answered when they merge it.

Answer (score 3):

Lets break down what apt-get is telling us:

- fonts-roboto was already installed and at the latest version.
- fonts-roboto-hinted was already installed and at the latest version. It was automatically installed with another package before, so now apt-get changed it to "manually installed" because you specifically asked for it to be
  installed.
- fonts-roboto-unhinted was not installed because it
  conflicts with fonts-roboto-hinted
- fonts-roboto-fontface was not installed. I don't see it listed in the output besides that it was selected.

In my research, I found a bug report for fonts-roboto on Debian (the distro Ubuntu is based on):
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=838199
The bug report is for the package conflict between fonts-roboto-hinted and fonts-roboto-unhinted. In the report, a developer says he fixed the issue in package version fonts-roboto 2:0~20160106-2

I'm not sure of a good way to handle this 'false' conflict because if you manually install both of the packages I think apt-get will complain about the conflict and will not be happy about it. It may also cause upgrades to fail. Perhaps someone with more knowledge can chime in on how to solve that situation.

You may want to run:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-roboto-fontface
```

Because I don't think it was installed and I don't think it will conflict.

Answer (score 2):

If other answers do not help you, here is how you can install them manually that's guaranteed to work:

1. Download roboto-master.zip from [here](https://codeload.github.com/google/roboto/zip/master).
2. Extract the file
3. Go to *roboto-master/src/hinted* inside the extracted file
4. Copy all TTF files to `/home/$USER/.local/share/fonts`

Comment: I did this but the fonts are still not showing up in chrome. Do i need to do anything else?

Comment: That should work so you are probably doing something wrong. Nonetheless, here is something else you can try. Download `http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fonts-roboto/fonts-roboto-hinted_0~20160106-2_all.deb` and see if you cam install it. If that fails, copy the files I originally asked you to: `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/hinted` - let us us know how you go.